# Unable to load image in symfony template +symonfy3.4

Tags: image, symfony, model-view-controller, assetic, symfony-3.4

```
 //index.html.php 
   <?php foreach ($view['assetic']->image(
        array('@AppBundle/Resources/public/images/test.png')
    ) as $url): ?>
        <div id="title">
            <h1><a href="/home/#"><img alt="logo" src="<?php 
                  echo $view->escape($url); ?>"> </a>
            </h1>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

Above is my code in template after adding, I executed *assetic:dump* and it generated a images in ***web/images/*** , still am not able to see images on my page. It is throwing 404 error for images.
Kindly let me know what going wrong here.

Note: Tried specifying image path in asset.yml and also LiipImagineBundle, nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

Assetics and assets are different.
do an `bin/console assets:dump` to put the resources of your bundle in the web directory then use your images like

```
<img src="<?php echo $view['assets']->getUrl('images/logo.png') ?>" />
```